# The message type 'EndOfStream' is not part of the service contract error while sending message to service broker

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, service-broker

I have following service broker:

**Message Type**

```
USE [DEV]
GO
ALTER MESSAGE TYPE [TestUpdateMessageType] VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML
```

**Contract**

```
USE [DEV]
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON CONTRACT::[TestContract] TO [dbo]
```

**Queue**

```
USE [DEV]
GO
ALTER QUEUE [dbo].[TestQueue] WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF , POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = OFF)
```

**Service**

```
USE [DEV]
GO
ALTER SERVICE [TestServiceName]  ON QUEUE [dbo].[TestQueue]
```

I am sending 100 records deserialized in XML format to this service broker queue using asp .net core. For sending this data, I am using stored procedure.

```
public async Task PushMessageToSBQ(string groupName, string payload)
{
    try
    {
        var dapperParameters = new DynamicParameters();
        dapperParameters.Add("@endpointGroup", groupName, dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
        dapperParameters.Add("@xmlPayload", payload, dbType: DbType.Xml, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);

        using (var executor = _executorFactory.GetDbExecutor())
        {
            executor.Execute([dbo].[SendMessage], dapperParameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I called this method I am getting following error.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException The message type 'EndOfStream' is not part of the service contract.
```

The `[dbo].[SendMessage]` which is used to send data is also working fine, I have checked it multiple time with different service broker queue. I don't know why this issue is occurring, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Post the proc code. Is there a reference to the `EndOfStream` message type in the proc?